# Can I use a UISearchController with a storyboard?

Tags: ios, uikit, uisearchbar, uistoryboard, uisearchcontroller

Is there a way to use `UISearchController` in a way that lets me storyboard the `UISearchBar`? I have a storyboarded UI with a navigation bar which contains my search bar. It would be great if I could keep it this way because setting up the layout programmatically would be really inconvenient. I know the old `UISearchDisplayController` could be storyboarded. Is there a way to do something similar with UISearchController?

Answer (score 5):

Add a `UIView` to your layout. That will be the container for your `UISearchBar`. Then programmatically instantiate the UISearchController and then add the searchbar to the container:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
searchBarContainer.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
```

Comment: But atfter going through this, it leaves a UINavigationBar at the top of the parent view controller view. And I couldn't figure out any way to dismiss it. What shall we do?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately that is not possible yet (iOS 10 and before).
See [this example code which was updated for iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html) that shows how to setup the UISearchController programmatically.