# How to assign searchBar of storyboard to searchController's searchBar property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

When I add my `searchBar` as a `headerView` of `tableView`, all the delegate methods are fired as expected.

1. `self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;`

But if I take a searchBar IBOutlet from StoryBoard and assign it to `self.searchController.searchBar`, delegated methods are not fired!

2. `_mySearchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;`

I've also tried embedding the `mySearchBar` into a view and then assign:

3. `_mySearchBarView = self.searchController.searchBar;`
   But no success!

Am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only way to do this is to subclass `UISearchController` and then set your custom `searchBar`:

> To use a custom subclass of `UISearchBar`, subclass `UISearchController` and implement this property to return your custom search bar.

[`UISearchController` `searchBar` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618657-searchbar?language=objc)

Comment: This is correct. A.) `UISearchController` is not currently available within the storyboard. B.) The only way to implement custom functionality with `UISearchController` or custom appearances is via subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

Your third method is almost perfect for doing what you want to, all you have to do is add the searchController.searchBar as the view's subview, rather than the view itself.

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
searchBarContainer.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
```

*searchBarContainer is your view in Storyboard.

This code is courtesy of *mylovemhz* who answered a similar question at this link: [Can I use a UISearchController with a storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556233/can-i-use-a-uisearchcontroller-with-a-storyboard)

Reposting it here for those who come to this thread on their search.

Comment: Thank you @peter-duniho for letting me know the best practices for answering a question on stackoverflow. First answer I've ever given!